# Laravel flysystem sftp upload slow

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, remote-server, laravel-filesystem

I need make upload to a remote server. I made a new disk in `filesystems.php`

And my upload code looks like this:

```
$path = 'storage1';
$fileName = Str::random().'.'. $request->file->getClientOriginalExtension();
Storage::disk('sftp')->putFileAs($path, $request->file, $fileName);
```

However, the upload takes a long time. On the frontend i have an upload progress bar which gets stuck 100% (upload via AJAX).

1. I will select a file - the progress bar will start
2. Only when it is 100% does the file actually start writing to the remote disk
3. Only when the file is uploaded to the remote server and then I get an ajax response from the server

**Is the file uploaded to some php `/tmp/` first and then when it is uploaded will it start uploading to the remote server?**
Is it possible to bypass it so that it goes directly there? Or do upload to a remote server via a background job, first upload to webstorage and then move to remote server on background?

My next question is how to do "disk loadbalancing"?
For example, I have 3 disks mounted on server. How I check disk `/storage1/` how much free space does it have? If it has more than 80% of total capacity then choose to upload to `/storage2/`

Comment: how much size is your file?

Comment: about 50-300mb primary mp3 files

Comment: please check your upload_max_filesize in php.ini.
refer more https://www.tecmint.com/increase-file-upload-size-in-php/

Comment: @manu that would make the upload fail, it would not make the upload slow

Comment: @manu upload_max_filesize I have 1GB, the file will be uploaded without any problems, it just takes a lot of time to transfer to the remote server. Uploading to the same server takes half the time less